# QML 2D Array of rectangles; access via C++

Tags: qt, qml

Simple tasks: I have a 2D array of which each element represents the color of an rectangle. I want this to be displayd in QML. Here is the qml:

```
    Rectangle {
    Grid {
        Repeater {
            model: myModel
            Rectangle {
                width: 50; height: 50
                color: ColorRole
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The ColorRole was used by an QAbstractTableModel derived class. Unfortunately, this did not seem to be the right solution as it did not work out as expected. Any ideas?

Edit:

Expected: An 8x8 array of rectangles arranged e.g. in a gridview:

```
Item {
Grid {
    id: gridarray
    Repeater {
             model: myModel
             Rectangle {
                 width: 50
                 height: 50
                 color: ColorRole
             }
    }
}
```

}

In C++ I have a derived class from QAbstractTabelModel to have a 2D array representation of the 2D grid view. I need to bring  this together somehow to change the color of each rectangle from the C++ model.

Comment: What a problem to pass it from C++ as a string or object list to the `Repeater.model`?

Comment: But then you have to transform a 1D list to an 2D array. The 2D array must be fixed to a given value like 8x8. Where each item represents a rectangle and I want to control the color of each rectangle.

Comment: Can you post a code when you create the 2D array and what will be expected output in this case.

Comment: see my edit above. C++ QAbstractTabelModel exmaples can be found everywhere around the net i guess.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://cdn.tutsplus.com/gamedev/authors/legacy/Stephane%20Beniak/2012/09/11/Preview_Image.png